# windows phone 10 emulator no internet

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-power-tools

I´m using Visual Studio 2015 to emulate Windows Phones. To start these machines I run "Windows Phone Developer Tools 8.1" which lists my available machines.

Mobile Emulator 10.0.14393 starts well and shows a virtual Windows phone but it cannot access the internet. Any idea why it can´t connect?

With Mobile Emulator 10.0.10586 it works fine with same machine. Emulator 8.1 too.

Only the new Emulator won´t connect to the internet. I repaired the tool installation and checked the hyper-v virtual Switches.

When I run the emulator this Network Connection in Tools shown:

```
Emulator-Adapter #1: 
Physische Adresse: 02DFDFDFDF02 
Virtueller Switch: Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch 
Netzwerkadressen: fe80::e16a:5fab:58ed:b38a (Bevorzugt)
172.16.80.2 (Bevorzugt) 
Emulator-Adapter #2: 
(Nur zu Diagnosezwecken verwendet) 
Physische Adresse: 02DEDEDEDE02 
Virtueller Switch: Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch 
Netzwerkadressen: fe80::9816:2cd1:504e:9498 (Bevorzugt)
169.254.148.152 (Bevorzugt) 
Emulator-Adapter #3: 
Physische Adresse: 00155D500200 
Virtueller Switch:  
Netzwerkadressen: fe80::45a:3f7c:a01b:cc8a
169.254.204.138
```

In the Network Adapter configuration the IPv4 Address is configured to DHCP.
Any ideas why it can´t use the Internet and all other Emulator can use it?

Anyone can use the emulator 10.0.14393 correctly with Internet Connection?

Kind regards

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I am having the same issue. I tried emulator version 10.0.10240.0 in the same machine and its internet is working fine. I am working behind corporate proxy, to give you more context.